# Reused cell is lagging in refreshing image

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

The main problem here is that I am loading images into a custom cell, and when scrolling, the reused cell shows the old image while loading the new image.

Frankly, there aren't going to be a lot of cells so my first thought was that I could get around using tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but every place I look to try and figure this out either people question why someone would do this, or they simply provide vague advice without some sort of example.

What is the best way to show a cell without this lag in reprocessing the image?

[image]

```
class FavoritesPropertyViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellPropertyImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellRoomsValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellSpaceValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellPriceRangeValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellCityStateZipValue: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cellAddressValue: UILabel!

}
```

---

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{         


            var newPropertyCell: FavoritesPropertyViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FavoritesPropertyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FavoritesPropertyViewCell

//... Get image, format values ...


                // Put everything in the labels.
                newPropertyCell.cellRoomsValue.text = roomsValue
                newPropertyCell.cellSpaceValue.text = spaceValue
                newPropertyCell.cellPriceRangeValue.text = priceValue
                newPropertyCell.cellAddressValue.text = addressValue
                newPropertyCell.cellCityStateZipValue.text = cityStateZipValue

                return newPropertyCell

    }
```

Comment: How might I use this without using tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot solve the problem when you are using the standard UIImageView because of scrolling speed vs network loading speed.

What my experience shows that it is definitely needed to use image cache.
There are some of cocoapods implement image cache and you might check AsyncImageView or [NPRImageView](http://cocoapods.org/?q=on%3Aios%20NPRImage)

Comment: I did eventually incorporate an image cache and that made a Huge difference.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a placeholder image and set the image to that when the cell is initialised and reused, put something like this in your MyCell.m:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];

    UIImage *placeHolder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profilePlaceholder"];
    self.propertyImage=placeholder;

}

-(void)prepareForReuse {

    //this is called each time we reuse a cell
    UIImage *placeHolder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"profilePlaceHolder"];
    self,propertyImage=placeHolder;

}
```

Now what you also want to do is create an image cache this can just be a NSMutableDictionary, then in your cell creation do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImage *cachedImage = self.images[cell.propertyName];
            if (cachedImage) {
                //use cached image
                cell.propertyImage=cachedImage;
            }

            else {

                 //your image download code here



                 //then add the image to the dictionary
                 [self.images setObject:downloadedImage forKey:cell.popertyName];

                //and set it
                cell.propertyImage = downloadedImage;
}
```

Those are the basics anyway.

if you don't want to use the dequeue then just change the cell creation to:

```
MyCell *cell = [[MyCell init] alloc];
```

or however you init your cell...

Comment: How might I do this without using tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Comment: why don't you want to use the dequeue? It will only make your table more efficient and it's easy to set up.

Comment: You really should be using it though. All you have to do is set the identifier in the interface builder....there's not really any extra code.

Comment: I get that Kex, I really do. I understand why, however, as I demonstrated in my question, using it means that there is a lag in switching between cells when the system reuses.  And if the idea behind cell reuse is to save memory, then it sort of defeats the purpose of creating an image cache as I am just saving the bulk of that data (the images) into memory anyways.

I will continued to explore this and see if I might just remove the images in advance or reusing, but with limited data going into this table view, I don't think not using it would be that big of an issue.

Comment: The image you posted off your app. It's switching between two different placeholders images. Both of those are stored locally right? If it's local there shouldn't be a problem with the image changing that slow

Comment: The images in the example are stored local, that is true, however there is a process that looks for images from an API, and then uses the URL to fetch the image if it is passed back.  So there is a little bit of network lag when figuring out whether there are images, and if there aren't then it loads the local place holder.  And this is why there is a lag to begin with.

And that is find, I have an activity indicator to occupy the space while it is figuring out where to get the images from.  The biggest issue is that the image from the cell it is reusing doesn't get dropped prior to displaying

Comment: why can't you just use the placeholder before the API call? Is it because you use two different types of placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

If you're loading the image from the network, try setting `cell.image = nil` before setting the new image. It will at least clear out the image while the next one loads in its place.

Comment: Since this is a custom cell, the image would have to be referenced differently and i tried setting it to nil but it gave me a bit of a fit.  I tried this a few different ways today but I will re-touch on it tomorrow and see if there is something i missed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to step around using tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier short of putting the cell into its own xib and calling it that way (which I might end up doing in the long run) however, to prevent what appears to be this reloading of the images, for now I am simply going to set the image to a placeholder right after I instantiate newPropertyCell.

Referencing an image that doesn't exist will bring back nothing which is pretty much what I want to have happen.

Note : "placeholder" is a reference to a file that doesn't exist but rather than error it returns nothing.

```
var newPropertyCell: FavoritesPropertyViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FavoritesPropertyCell") as FavoritesPropertyViewCell

newPropertyCell.cellPropertyImage.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
```

At a later time I might come back and cache the images so that there is greater persistence and I won't have to hit the API to check for images, or download it again as it is scrolled.

Thanks all!

Comment: Side note : setting the image to "nil" doesn't work in swift.